# How to maintain node_modules and packages dependencies clean using npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

What are you doing when you use npm and maintain your node_modules clean?
I am always annoyed with the packages dependence becomes messy and node_modules gets bloated when I install various libraries or plugins using npm (without thinking deeply).

I always try following commands...

`$ npm outdated` (check updates)

`$ npm update Some-Package` (update)

`$ npm dedupe`  (simplify dependencies)

`$ npm prune` (delete unnecessary packages)

then

`$ npm Init`

I would like to let you know if there are other recommended methods or practice such as this. 
Thank you.